# Optimal font size in TIA Portal with least disadvantages

Tags: plc

I have thought about working with TIA Portal a lot recently.
My eyes are still good, but I can feel the stress when working with TIA.

This question is here to discuss the pro's and con's of different methods to improve working with TIA and care for ones eyes.

My Notebook has a full-HD screen with 17 Inches.
If I work with TIA, I do not just have the TIA open, but need a variety of other applications, like Browser, Excel, specialized tools, PDF-Reader.......
The operating system is Windows 10.

At the moment I decided, to reduce the screen resolution so all texts within TIA are comfortably readable.
The big disadvantage are applications, that are designed for higher resolutions.
I can't change the resolution based on the application in focus.

If there would only be an option within TIA, but I can't find one.

Any thoughts about improving the situation are highly appreciated to keep peoples eyes healthy.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

1. Use the display scaling in Windows 10 instead of changing the resolution. You can find it at Settings > System > Display. [(see this answer as well)](https://superuser.com/questions/951199/windows-10-system-font-size-change)
2. I use a second 24" display for the programming work in the office, which is about 80% of the time.

Comment: Thanks for the Input. The Windows 10 scaling is too much of a global thing, and for some applications ruins the work, therefor the scaling would only be good if applicable just for the TIA.

Comment: As for the second screen... it sure helps but in my case are 3 screens at once or only just the notebook screen, but in all configurations TIA is a problem. Comissioners usually have more applications opened than just TIA (on one small screen) and should have the option to alter the scaling "just" for TIA. Unless there is a solution to that TIA will be a job motor for opticians.